# Check Percentage of Hard Usage script

Tags: bash

Need a script that does a du -m --summarize on a series of directories for people to identify that outputs the information about certain directories such as %, size, without them having to cd and manually check like this:

```
tmpfs                      7.8G  8.2M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5.0M   12K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                      7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

The usage needs to be below 90%. so far I got

```
#!/bin/bash
df -Ph | awk '+$5>=10 || $1=="Filesystem"' 
if df -Ph | awk '+$5<=10 || $1=="Filesystem" { if ( +$5<=10) exit(1) ; else exit(0) }'
then du -h | sort -nr | head -10 
else  echo Fail usage is less from 10%
fi
```

not sure if that covers multiple directories

Comment: Goto a directory where you know there are child dirs and further subdirs, and then run the `du -h` without any `|.....` and see for yourself? Compare that to the output of `du -h *`. Good luck.

Comment: Had forgot about my goto `du` test, use `du -sh *` from the parent dir. This summarizes all child dirs below the first level, so `./local/bin` is totaled into the value for `./local`, just for example. Not clear if this will help you, but I offer it, just in case. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would suggest is to reduce the noise output from the original df command and so use:

```
df --output=target,pcent
```

This will give you just the target mount point in the first column and then the percentage used in the second.

For your du command, you will need either to be in the directory you want to check the space for or, use the directory as part of the command. I would also think about the depth you want to check (how many directories down in the tree structure) This causes issues in your solution as the awk statement simply returns an exit code and no mount point to either cd into or use in the du command

If you are looking for du data for mount points over 10%, I would therefore write a solution as follows:

```
 df --output=target,pcent | awk '+$2 > 10 { system("du -h --max-depth=1 "$1) } +$2 <= 10 { print $1" - Usage less than 10%" }'
```

For percentages over 10 (+$2) use awk's system function to execute a du command with a max depth of 1 on the mount-point (directory) - $1. In all other cases. print that "usage is less than 10%"

Note - As the du command is being built within awk, I would always suggest printing the command before execution and so run the awk command with print instead of system to verify that the commands to be executed are correct before actual execution with the system function and so:

```
df --output=target,pcent | awk '+$2 > 10 { print "du -h --max-depth=1 "$1 } +$2 <= 10 { print $1" - Usage less than 10%" }'
```